# How can I check code offline using the same rules as SonarQube?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint

I need to check the code locally using the same rules as SonarQube, and I found that '**SonarLint**' can be used.
However, it cannot be run as '**pytest /worker/tests**' to check the specific paths I want to examine or raise error.

This is what i needed

- "using the same rules as SonarQube"
- "can be executed **locally**, either in an IDE (VS Code) or via the terminal"

Then I can push my code after checking locally